# Is it OK to assign the input from Java Scanner to a variable inside the while loop condition?

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

For example, like this.

```
while ((input = kb.nextInt()) != 0) {
            if (input % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("even");
            } else {
                System.out.println("odd");
            }
```

instead of only checking the value of the input variable inside the condition and getting the number from Scanner inside the loop, like so:

```
while (input != 0) {
            input = kb.nextInt();
...code here...
```

Just wondering if the first one is bad practice or anything like that.

Comment: I have seen both getting used. Although I like the second one better. I like to keep the condition inside the while loop simple. It should be very apparent when this loop will terminate for better readability.

Comment: Well the second approach would be more readable, maintainable and testable than the first one and this is what the clean code principles says : "Keep it simple, readable  maintainable and testable". So you should apply the second one than the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `nextInt()` as part of a loop condition, while perfectly legal, can be problematic from the standpoint of dealing with errors arising from **bad input**.  Actual humans sitting in front of a keyboard entering data (which the `Scanner` variable name `kb` seems to suggest is exactly what you're dealing with here) are notoriously unreliable in terms of their data entry quality, so **bad input** is something you should be prepared for.

`nextInt()` will throw an `InputMismatchException` exception if the next available input is not a valid representation of an integer.  In order to catch and handle this exception, the `nextInt()` call must be executed inside of a `try` block.  However, with the `nextInt()` being part of the control condition of the `while` loop, the only way to do that is to enclose the entire loop in the `try` block:

```
try {
    while ((input = kb.nextInt()) != 0){
       ...
    }
} catch (InputMismatchException ime){
     ...
}
```

Unfortunately, this means that any exception raised by `nextInt()` will kill the `while` loop.  If you wanted to keep processing user inputs after an input error, you'd have to provide a means of starting the `while` loop over again, and keep starting it over until the "real" user-signaled end-of-input condition had been reached.  You *might* be able to do it with a clunky workaround like this one:

```
boolean keepGoing = true;
while (keepGoing){
    try {
        while ((input = kb.nextInt()) != 0) {
           ...
        }
        keepGoing = false;  
    } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
        String junk = kb.next();
        System.out.println("Didn't understand your input: " + junk);
        System.out.println("Please type a valid integer");
    }
}
```

But depending on what the `...` code inside the loop was doing, this relatively simple workaround might be inadequate; you might need something even more complicated and unreadable.

But by moving the `nextInt()` call out of the control logic of the loop and into the loop body, you gain considerable flexibility in terms of your options for recovery from bad input.  With `nextInt()` inside the loop body, you can now catch and handle any exception entirely within one iteration of the loop, without having to terminate the loop itself:

```
do {
    try {
        input = kb.next();
        if (input != 0) {
            ...
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchedException ime) {
        String junk = kb.next();
        System.out.println("Didn't understand your input: " + junk);
        System.out.println("Please type a valid integer");
    } 
} while (input != 0);
```

You'd also have the option of avoiding an exception altogether by using `hasNextInt()` to ensure that a valid input is present before trying to read it with `nextInt()`:

```
for(;;) {
    if (!kb.hasNextInt()) {
        String junk = kb.next();
        System.out.println("Didn't understand your input: " + junk);
        System.out.println("Please type a valid integer");
    } else {
        input = kb.nextInt();
        if (input == 0) {
            break;
        else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one doesn't have the input defined for testing the condition `input!=0` hence the first one is right but if you're going to use the second format I'd suggest to change the `while` loop to `do-while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your two code samples are not equivalent and do different things (the second version probably doing not what you want it to do).
You would need another `if (input != 0)` inside the loop and assignment of `input` before the loop for the second version. Moving the assignment to the end and duplicating it before the loop is also a viable option:

```
input = kb.nextInt();
while (input != 0) {
    if (input % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("even");
    } else {
        System.out.println("odd");
    }
    input = kb.nextInt();
}
```

And the duplicated first and last line in this version is very likely the reason for the somewhat complicated code. This type of loop `loop ((x = input()) != 0)` can be seen in a lot of C code but is sometimes "required" in Java too when you want to reduce code-duplication when processing input. This is caused by the fact that `nextInt` returns a value and mutates the underlying state.